# How to secured many java web applications

Tags: java, spring, oauth, spring-cloud-security

I have three java web applications in one server and I want to connect on all applications with a single login. I want to use oauth with spring cloud security.

someone can help me please!!!

Comment: show us the money

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need authenticate users using jradius or ldap (active directory).
Spring Security can use central auth point.